# The select2 selector does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to use select2 to load the result of a query that returns a string in json format.
I load the data well in the select2 but I do not get the way the selector works at the time of clicking.

Here the code:

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ path("ajax_search_client") }}",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        data: params.term, // search term
                        page: params.page
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                    // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                    // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
                    // scrolling can be used
                    params.page = params.page || 1;
                    obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(obj.length);

                    return {
                        results: obj,
                        pagination: {
                            more: (params.page * 30) < obj.length
                        }
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            placeholder: 'Buscar un cliente',
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            templateResult: formatRepo,
            templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
        });

        function formatRepo (repo) {

            if (repo.loading) {
                return repo.text;
            }

            console.log(repo);
            var client_data = repo.split('"');
            console.log(client_data);

            var item = "'"+client_data[3]+"'";

            var markup = '<div class="select2-result-repository clearfix" onClick="tradename(' + item + ')">' +
                '<div class="select2-result-repository__avatar"><img src="" /></div>' +
                '<div class="select2-result-repository__meta">' +
                '<div class="select2-result-repository__title"><strong>' + client_data[3] + '</strong></div>';

            /*if (repo.description) {
                markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" +  + "</div>";
            }*/

            markup += '<div class="select2-result-repository__statistics">' +
                '<div class="select2-result-repository__forks"> ' + client_data[7] + '</div>' +
                '<div class="select2-result-repository__stargazers"> ' + client_data[11] + '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div></div>';

            return markup;
        }

        function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
            return repo.full_name || repo.text;
        }
```

data content:

> ["{\"tradename\" :\"pascual\",\"fiscalname\" :\"pascual sl\",\"nif\"
>   :\"4568424\"},","{\"tradename\" :\"Jacinto\",\"fiscalname\" :\"Jacinto
>   sl\",\"nif\" :\"8764564\"},","{\"tradename\"
>   :\"Calzapeques\",\"fiscalname\" :\"Calzapeques sl\",\"nif\"
>   :\"4568753\"},"]

obj content:

> ["{"tradename" :"pascual","fiscalname" :"pascual sl","nif"
>   :"4568424"},", "{"tradename" :"Jacinto","fiscalname" :"Jacinto
>   sl","nif" :"8764564"},", "{"tradename" :"Calzapeques","fiscalname"
>   :"Calzapeques sl","nif" :"4568753"},"]